# Center Table Of Contents In Center. Sticky Div Like Functionality

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

So I've been recently trying to implement this feature from this [blog](https://www.trajectorywebdesign.com/blog/choosing-a-web-design-agency/#2-industry-research). Where the Table of Contents, Moves with the scrolling, but stops at both ends of the Content Container.

I couldn't find an answer to this question, so some pointers in the right direction would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for the CSS attribute `position: sticky`. An element with this attribute set will *stick* to the top of the screen once it is covered by the top of the viewport. However, the element is still confined to its container. If you scroll far enough and the content of your element would exceed the bottom of the container, it will also start to scroll out of the viewport.

All you have to do is add something like this to your CSS and make sure that your TOC is part of a container that defines the area where the TOC should be visible:

```css
.toc {
  position: sticky;
  top: 10px;
}
```

The `top` attribute lets you specify the distance to the top of the viewport when the element becomes sticky.

Here is a full example: https://codepen.io/mmueller2012/pen/gOdKgRx